# Public Sharepoint site with custom user registration

Tags: forms-authentication, public-website

We are doing a public site with external user registration based on Sharepoint 2010. We have some experience in ASP.NET development but nobody has any experience with Sharepoint. What is a relatively simple thing to do in ASP.NET, after doing some research in the web we found  that it is not so straight forward in Sharepoint. So we would appreciate some advice for the right approach.

First of all, we have to do a custom registration form with all the information we need, including file uploads, have a SQL Server Database table to store all data, and use FBA (or another method) in Sharepoint to authenticate against it.

Then we need an administrator (AD user) to validate registration and automatically generate a password that will be send to the user. The user can only login after this validation.

Last, we must implement a two way login, a classic username/password and the other method is against an Identity Provider in another website (need to redirect) with a SAML request, after the response we have to compare and validate the response with the user data in Database.

Is all of this doable with Sharepoint? What is the best approach? How difficult can this be for a begginner Sharepoint developer?

Thanks in advance.
Nuno

Comment: Nuno Pinto, I am facing the same problem . pls help me out from this . I am creating a website where user can register himself and after mail verification user can able to login . I have all the code in asp.net net. pls help me out how i authenticate user with cumstom sql 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neno,

It seems quite a difficult task for a beginner to work on SharePoint Anonymous site...

Normally as you know SharePoint websites are authenticated with your Active Directory users but you can implement different authentication methods, one is Forms Based Authentication for which you can use ASP.NET Membership Provider as we usually use in ASP.NET applications...

For FBA [Form Based Authentication with ASP.NET Membership], there are very nice codeplex projects:

http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/

http://sp2010fba.codeplex.com/

Use the one which is suitable to you... The second thing you have asked for is Authentication via some other website, SharePoint can use Windows Live ID/Hotmail for authentication but I really don't know which website you are talking about, can you please mention the name of the website?

However there can be a possibility of making your custom Login page for SharePoint which these codeplex solutions also do! In that you are free to write code and can authenticate via writing code behind...

I hope this helps!

Comment: Nuno, mark it as answer if this was helpful :P, or atleast you can upmark the post man!

Comment: Arsalan, thanks for the reply. Sorry, I can't tell you the website name, but basically, it authenticates a user based on a RSA-SHA1 certificate, gets the information we ask in the SAML request and redirect again to us with the response. That response will be an unique number that is in our database. But it's not like Windows Live ID authentication. Sorry for the previous incomplete answer.

Comment: Nuno, the users authenticated from that 3rd party website are actually same as that in your database right ? Do they have any mapping in the database? I guess, you give a try to making custom login page in SharePoint 2010... and let me know what you experience! Follow this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/22/writing-a-custom-forms-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010-part-2.aspx

Comment: No problem, Anytime! :)